# A Python infinite loop with arguments that can be manually changed as the script runs

Tags: python, config, infinite-loop

This is my attempt to begin creating a script that runs in "real-time" with parameters that can be changed while the script runs.

My idea is that there will be a Python script that runs as an infinite loop:

***output.py***

```
while True:
    print(0)
```

It always outputs `0`. There will be a file, right now my guess is a config.ini file (or something similar), where I can set times that the output is `1`. Something like:

***config.ini***

```
[INPUT]
times = [[4000, 6000], [25000, 55000]]
```

**Note:** I am imagining this as a 24hr scale in seconds (86400 seconds), and the intervals are in seconds.

How it works:

1. I start ***output.py*** and it begins running from the current GMT in seconds
2. I enter my time intervals (i.e. `[[4000, 6000], [25000, 55000]]`) into ***config.ini*** where the output is `1`
3. ***output.py*** is consistently "checking" ***config.ini*** and importing newly entered time intervals where `0` will be changed to `1`, as well as checking if a scheduled time interval was deleted
4. When the time that has been entered into ***config.ini*** occurs (i.e. `[4000, 6000]`), the output is set to `1` for the duration of the interval that was entered. Once over, the output goes back to `0` and does not become `1` again until another scheduled interval is reached (i.e. `[25000, 55000]`) .

Additional points:

- The ***config.ini*** file is consistently being "checked" by ***output.py*** for new intervals where the output will be `1` instead of `0`. The "checking" would be on the scale of minutes, maybe seconds.
- ***output.py*** "resets" every time GMT reaches midnight
- ***output.py*** is working on an actual real life time scale, so output is actually being outputted every second
- There could be any number of time intervals entered into ***config.ini***, or none at all
- ***config.ini*** can be changed at any time while ***output.py*** is running
- `0` and `1` can be thought of as being on the y-axis, and the time intervals being on the x-axis
- When ***output.py*** resets at midnight GMT, if the time intervals are still in ***config.ini*** (i.e. `[[4000, 6000], [25000, 55000]]`), they will just be applied again at the specified times.

As I mentioned before, it does not need to be a config.ini file, it could be a .txt, or some other type of file, maybe even a database. What I ideally want to use is something that can be modified where entries and deletions can be done manually (I enter and delete time intervals), or automatically (a separate Python script can enter and delete intervals in the config.ini file).

Let me know if clarification is needed. This is a problem I have been trying to figure out for some time, and I would like to have a working example to build off of.

Comment: Stack Overflow is more for when you have written some code but are having trouble getting it to work the way you want. You're essentially asking others to write your whole program for you. That's not how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @kindall Thank you for letting me know how Stack Overflow works. This is not a problem that I have seen done, and I personally do not know what to Google, or search on SO to find a similar problem. If you have suggestions on topics related to my questions that I can research, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

To read INI files, you can use configparser module. Or ConfigParser in Py2.

To pickup new args you set an interval, let say 1 sec or more, and use:

```
os.path.getmtime("your_file.txt")
```

if the modification time changed from last time, you reload the arguments.
You may use the Timer() from threading module to activate different actions and a loop that manipulates the timers according to new args.
Or you can make a loop checking different intervals like this:

```
from time import time, sleep

act_time = time()
check_args = 1.0
while 1:
    current_time = time()
    if current_time-act_time>=check_args:
        reload_args()
        act_time = current_time
        continue
    # And other similar checks according to other vars updated by reload_args() function
    sleep(0.001) # Prevent a busy loop
```

Of course, instead of using time() and resetting
act_time, you can make your own time keeping variable and add 0.001 to it after the sleep(). But you still need a reliable way to check how much time passed for each interval you are checking for and add to them too, so you have to way this things. Nobody will write more code than this for you here. Good luck.